# Query to firestore data returns database credentials instead of collection or document

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

When I query data from my NestJS app I get a JSON object that seems to consist of everything about my database except the data I'm querying.  I has my private key, the firestore version, the time it was created, all sorts of stuff.  Not only do I want to know how to correct this issue but I want to know how to prevent the current results from being queried the way I'm querying it because I imagine someone could easily hack my database this way.

I connect to the database using the method outlined in the doc pages which is the code below.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../path_to_my_file");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "link_to_database"
});

const db = admin.firestore();
```

I run `firebase serve --only functions` and make the query in my service file like this

```
async getSampleData(){
    const dataFetcher = db.collection('product_index_list').doc('golden_ratio_dividers');

    return await dataFetcher.get();
    
  }
```

In my NestJS Controller I have this function which sends the request to the `getSampleData()` function in the service.

```
@Get('get-sample-data')
getSampleData(){ return this.appService.getSampleData(); }
```

So when I navigate to `localhost:3333/api/get-sample-data` I get back the following object which I stripped of all the values

```
{
    "_fieldsProto":{
        "title":{
            "stringValue":"Golden Ratio Dividers",
            "valueType":"stringValue"
        }
    },
    "_ref":{
        "_firestore":{
            "_settings":{
                "credentials":{
                    "private_key":"******",
                    "client_email":"***"
                },
                "projectId":"***",
                "firebaseVersion":"***",
                "libName":"****",
                "libVersion":"***",
                "servicePath":"****",
                "port":******,
                "clientConfig":{},
                "scopes":["*****","****"]
            },
            "_settingsFrozen":*****,
            "_serializer":{
                "allowUndefined":***
            },
            "_projectId":"*****",
            "registeredListenersCount":***,
            "_lastSuccessfulRequest":********,
            "_backoffSettings":{
                "initialDelayMs":****,
                "maxDelayMs":****,
                "backoffFactor":****
            },
            "_preferTransactions":****,
            "_clientPool":{
                "concurrentOperationLimit":****,
                "maxIdleClients":***,
                "activeClients":{},
                "terminated":****,
                "terminateDeferred":{
                    "promise":{}
                }
            }
        },
        "_path":{
            "segments":["*****","******"]
        },
        "_converter":{}
    },
    "_serializer":{
        "allowUndefined":****
    },
    "_readTime":{
        "_seconds":****,
        "_nanoseconds"****
    },
    "_createTime":{
        "_seconds":******,
        "_nanoseconds":******
    },
    "_updateTime":{
        "_seconds":*****,
        "_nanoseconds":******
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here with the way I'm calling my data and how can I make sure I can guard against someone being able to just make this same request to get my credentials?

Comment: We have no way to see how `getSampleData` is called, or how its return value is being used. Can you update your code to log the problematic values, and then edit your question to include the updated code and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the entire [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) to the caller. In addition to the data from your document, that contains some public metadata, and some internal information as you see in your return value. From a quick scan none of that information is secret, but even then I agree it's not necessary to return it here.

You'll want to selectively return the information from the `DocumentSnapshot`. At the very least that'll be `DocumentSnapshot.data`, but check out the documentation of the [`DocumentSnapshot` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) to see if there's more your clients need.

Comment: can you show an example because I've been reading up on `DocumentSnapshot` the past couple days and can't figure out how or where I'm suppose to use it.

Comment: `return await dataFetcher.get().data();`?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying dataFetcher.get().data() ins't a function.

Comment: Yeah, that might be `return await (dataFetcher.get()).data()`, so that the await covers the `get()`.

Comment: I'd beg to differ that your service account's private key is not secret...

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it now, it makes sense that the snapshot object holds credentials as it needs to be able to query Firestore on its own. But leaking this information to a malicious user may have fatal consequences as they'd obtain admin access to your Firebase project.

I don't have a clear opinion on how to prevent this from happening. For now I guess I'll go with this simple function that should prevent the worst-case scenario even if all other precautions fail.

```
import * as express from 'express'
function addValidation(this: any, res: express.Response) {
  const originalSend = res.send
  res.send = function (response: any): express.Response {
    if (response && response._firestore) {
      return res.status(500).send({ error: 'FATAL: Attempt to send an invalid response' })
    } else {
    return originalSend.bind(this)(response)
    }
  }
}

function sendResponseSafe(res: express.Response, callback: () => Promise<void>) {
  addValidation(res)
  callback()
}

export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
  return sendResponseSafe(res, () => _getUser(req, res))
})
```

Comment: `_firestore` key can also be nested into a response children